# Create a URL hyperlink (href) using getElementById from user Input

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href, getelementbyid

Is there a way I can create a hyperlink or Link based from getElementById from user inputs?

This is my code for user inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
<br><button type="button" onClick="generateURLX();">Generate URL</button></br>
```

This is the part where I determine those id in a function

```
<script>
function generateURLX()
{
var partx = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
var party = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
var urlx = "https://example.com/"+partx+"/"+party+".html";
document.getElementById('resultx').innerHTML = urlx;
</script>
```

And this is where I display the hyperlink:

```
<span id="resultx"></span>
```

I tried using <a href but I failed on making a hyperlink for that specific id=resultx which is basically based from var urlx

```
<a href="#resultx"></a>
```

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it helped me on familiarizing to create a simple hyperlink. But the problem I'm having is that, I do not predetermine the link, the hyperlink will be created based from the user inputs I've shown from the post. Basically; a user inputs his First and last name and my code should output a hyperlink of a website based from the inputted first and last name, for Example ; James Smith, the hyperlink should output https://example.com/James/Smith.html. I hope you understand it. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, you computed the value of `urlx` right?

What you need is an identifier for the hyperlink you want to address, then you can use something like this:

HTML

```html
    <a id="linkx" href=""><;/a>
```

CODE

```js
    document.getElemebtById("linkx").href = urlx;
```

And it should work ok.